# integer expression expected while running the bash script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

While running my below script from the jenkins's execute shell option, I'm getting -- **[: 1 2 3 4 5 : integer expression expected**, I tried using > symbol too without any lucks, I'm not sure exactly where I went wrong.

Any help will be really helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a folders
declare -a folders_req

db_ver=<the value which I got from my DB with trimmed leading & trailing spaces, like below> 
#db_ver=`echo $( get_value ) |sed -e 's/\-//g' | grep -oP '(?<=DESCRIPTION)(\s+)?([^ ]*)'  | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]//g' | sed -e's/[[:space:]]*$//' | tr '\n' ' '| cut -d '/' -f2`

scripts_db_dir=`ls -td -- */ | head -1 | cut -d '/' -f1| sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]//g'`

cd ${scripts_db_dir}
folders=`ls -d */ | sed 's/\///g' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]//g' | sed -e's/[[:space:]]*$//' | tr '\n' ' '`

  for i in "${folders[@]}"; do

    if [ "${i}" -gt "${db_ver}" ]; then
       echo "inside loop: $i"
       folders_req+=("$i")
    fi
  done

  #echo "$i"
  #echo ${folders_req[@]}
```

scripts_db_dir contains directory named like -  1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Maybe you can further simplify the question by finding the exact line of error. Try running the script manually with following flags `bash -ex script.sh`. `-x` shows debug output, `-e` terminates execution right after the first non zero error code.

Comment: Also, I will point you to the famous page [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! I would suggest you to loop through directory content using a glob. e.g. `for file in *; do echo $file; done`

Comment: @anubis Except you should [quote the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Ah, yes ;) I overlooked that as it was an example. But you are correct.

Comment: @Anubis: Thank you for ur valuable input and the link shared :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `folders` variable should be initialized as an array and not as a string, eg :

```
folders=($(ls -d */ | sed 's/\///g' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]//g' | sed -e's/[[:space:]]*$//' | tr '\n' ' '))
```

Comment: ... Which probably is better written `folders=(*/)` if I'm guessing the intent correctly. Definitely avoid [parsing `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @funkyjelly: Worked perfectly, I was under impression that I've declared the array, so "ls parsed output" will be taken as an array.
Could you kindly give me links where I can read much into it, thanks

Comment: here's a [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-arrays-in-bash-script). I'd also suggest to take into account @tripleee suggestion in these comments.

Comment: `variable=string` (or `variable=\s\t\r\i\n\g` or `variable="string"` or `variable='string'` or `variable=$(echo string)` with a command substitution) creates a simple scalar variable. `variable=(expression)` creates an array.

Comment: funkyjelly & @tripleee :  vivid explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the various comments regarding "parsing `ls` is bad", consider using find instead:

`find * -maxdepth 1  -type d -name '[0-9]*' -print`

where:
`-maxdepth 1` -  searches only the current directory, no sub directories
`-type d`  -  looks only for directories
`-name '[0-9]*'`  (or `'[[:digit:]]*'`)  -  matches only items consisting of all digits
 
`-print` -  just print the results

Thus:
`folders=($(find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[0-9]*' -print))`
or just:
`for i in $(find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[0-9]*' -print); do`